# message not printed while using infinite loop

Tags: c, sockets, loops

I have written a program of server that just accepts the connection from client. For that the accept function in an infinite loop. but when it executes the message printed just before the loop does not get printed . My Code is:

```
     #include<stdio.h>
    #include<sys/socket.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<netinet/in.h>
    void main()
    {
    int sock,bind_sock,lis_sock,cli_sock,addr_len;
    struct sockaddr_in addr,cli_addr;

    if ((sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
            printf("\nsocket error");
    else
            printf("socket");
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port=htons(5012);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if((bind_sock=bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)))<0)
            printf("\nBound error");
     else
            printf("Bound");

    if((lis_sock=listen(sock,10))<0)
            printf("\nlisten error");
    else
            printf("listen\nwaiting for connection" );
    while(1)
    {
            addr_len=sizeof(cli_addr);
            cli_sock=accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&addr_len);
            if(cli_sock<0)
            printf("\nConnetion Error\n");
            else
            printf("conneted\n");

    }
```

}
and the output it gives is:

```
    ]$ ./a.out
   socketBoundlisten
```

Comment: @EdHeal `"waiting for connection"` is not printed - that's the problem

Comment: your not blocking the if else clause. please edit

Comment: You probably want to handle errors (return?) instead of continuing anyway with bad data. Not related to your problem at hand, just something I noticed.

Comment: Just telnet to the port. Also a google will give you http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/98174-c-program-client-server.html that is reasonable code.

Answer (score 2):

printf is line terminated so add \n to the end and check the output .example

> ```
>         printf("conneted \n");
> ```

Comment: There is no difference in the output after using \n in printf'

Answer (score 1):

chances are your "waiting for connection" may be buffered and may print when your client connects. Did you try connecting a client and seeing the output?

Also try this:

```
if((lis_sock=listen(sock,10))<0)
        printf("\nlisten error");
else
        printf("listen\nwaiting to connect");
```

Comment: if it has hit "listen" then there should be no reason why "waiting for connection" should be buffered right?

Comment: if it hit listen and "waiting for connection" was not buffered then "listen" would not get printed.

Comment: I had tried it but even after getting conneted it does not print  "waiting for connection" as well as "connected"

Comment: if its buffered then trying to flush it might give some idea.

Comment: @kanika post the entire code, let me run it and see the output.

Comment: @kanika a statement cannot just be "skipped" that way.

Comment: @kanika try `fflush(stdout);` after "waiting.."

Answer (score 1):

Try do this before printf.

> setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

Comment: It is `setvbuf`. It set stdout to No buffering mode.

Comment: setvbuf is good if you know the buffer size. but since you are Specifying NULL for the buf, its better to use setbuf(). not to mention lesser args;-). [link](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/setvbuf.html)

Answer (score 0):

kanika you mentioned that fflush(stdout) has solved so as aniket mentioned it was being buffered.
2 possible solutions for buffered printf

1) use `fflush(stdout)` because stdout is buffered and prints whats after newline.

OR

2)disable buffering by `setbuf(stdout,NULL)`.(or may be setvbuf).